# Spring+Thymeleaf+AngularJs: very first example: no errors, but is not working

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a `Spring MVC 4.2.6` project with `webjars` libraries and `Thymeleaf` framework, and I am trying this very simple example (let us call this template as `test.html` mapped in the controller to `/test`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
      th:fragment="page" ng-app>
<head>
    <title>First Test</title>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/angularjs/angular.js}" type="javascript"></script>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn btn-default">{{"AngularJS"}}</div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">Bootstrap</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All resources load fine, no errors in console, but `AngularJs` is not working (see the brackets in the screenshot):
[image]

What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

---

P.S. An example, slightly modified, is taken from the book "Pro AngularJS" by Adam Freeman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody. It wasn't working because I have automatically added `type="javascript"` into `<script .../>`. After removing it:

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/angularjs/angular.js}"></script>
```

it started working fine. (WHY!?).

Comment: You should change type="javascript" to type="text/javascript".